# MonoDevelop seems to hang (not unresponsive) when building csprojs

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, monodevelop

Building a solution from Visual Studio in mono develop seems to have some issues.  I'm hoping someone else has experienced this and has some suggestions.

The actual `dcms` process goes pretty quickly, but in between projects it hangs after printing:

```
Building: XXX.YYY.ZZZ (Debug)
```

After a few minutes (been 10 so far on this current run), it jumps to:

```
    Performing main compilation...
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.1/bin/dmcs /noconfig "/...
    Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings

Building: XXX.YYY.ZZZ (Debug)
```

Then hangs again for another few minutes.

This is a `sln` file with 29 `csproj` projects in it that was originally created in Visual Studio 2010.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to set this up - potentially a native MD file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD has its own system to build csproj.

Can you directly use xbuild to build it and test how long that takes?

Forget about native MD file format. It is time to switch to MSBuild script.

Comment: `xbuild thesolution.sln` flies through it - doens't hang between projects (doesn't succeed due to compilation errors, but that isn't related at the moment).

Comment: Also can you expand on 'time to switch to MSBuild script' - do you mean compile out side of MD using scripts that manually call xbuild?

Comment: I don't know what's the plan of MD team, but MD should switch to use xbuild as the underlying engine in the long term, http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2009/07/building-with-msbuildxbuild-in.html The only problem right now is that integration is still experimental and not perfect yet. So personally I always use a Terminal to execute xbuild.

Comment: Thank you :) That link helped.  Using xbuild from within MD now, works so much faster.